# how to upload the existing app in to web2py environment

Tags: python, web2py

I am new to web2py I have web2py application in my local system i want to upload this application into web2py environment throught admin interface option present in web2py Upload & install packed application and do some modifications and run the application but i am  unable to uploded the app please give the suggesations how to do this

Thanks in advance

Comment: As I understand you downloaded an existing Web2Py application and try to install it in your local system which is failing. Try updating web2py, or try a different browser.

Comment: The browser crashes? Could you be more specific on the error?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the file system.

**GUI:**

Copy your application folder to your new instance of web2py (/web2py/applications).

**Command line:**

scp -r /home/username/oldarea/web2py/application/myApp /home/username/newarea/web2py/applications